# Error in loading OpenNETCF 2.3 in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opennetcf

I've downloaded latest source code of version 2.3 and when I open it in VS2008 Pro I have an error message telling me that I must install Windows Mobile 6 Pro SDK.

So I've downloaded it and I'm struggling installing it because I have below error message: "COM3 is in use, please close Device Emulator if it's running and then retry".

[image]

I dont mind downloading the compiled dll of Open NET CF if it's available somewhere on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what the serial port message is talking about.  That said, I have updated the source tree with a couple things of interest:

1. I normalized the target platforms to "Windows CE" so you don't need the WinMo 6 SDK to open the solution any longer.
2. I added a new solution file that loads only the core assembly projects (i.e. no sample apps and no unit tests).
3. I added a binaries-only zip to the release download.

One or more of these should address the issues you're having.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will download your latest update when I'm back at the office. I'll let you know if I have any other issue. You're great!